# Are modern programming languages context-free?

Tags: formal-languages, programming-languages, syntax

Which language class are today's modern programming languages like Java, JavaScript, and Python in?

It appears (?) they are not context-free and not regular languages.

Are these programming languages context-sensitive or decidable languages? I am very confused!

I know that context-free is more powerful than regular languages and that context-sensitive is more powerful than context-free.

Are modern programming languages both context-free and context-sensitive?

Comment: @nirshahar "It has a grammar therefore it is context free" is not correct. It is fine and easy to define grammars which describe a language that is not context free.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Practically no programming language, modern or ancient, is truly context-free, regardless of what people will tell you. But it hardly matters. Every programming language can be parsed; otherwise, it wouldn't be very useful. So all the deviations from context freeness have been dealt with.

What people usually mean when they tell you that programming languages are context-free because somewhere in the documentation there's a context-free grammar, is that the set of well-formed programs (that is, the "language" in the sense of formal language theory) is a *subset* of a context-free grammar, conditioned by a set of constraints written in the rest of the language documentation. That's mostly how programs are parsed: a context-free grammar is used, which recognises all valid and some invalid programs, and then the resulting parse tree is traversed to apply the constraints.

To justify describing the language as "context-free", there's a tendency to say that these constraints are "semantic" (and therefore not part of the language syntax). [Note 1] But that's not a very meaningful use of the word "semantic", since rules like "every variable must be declared" (which is common, if by no means universal) is certainly syntactic in the sense that you can easily apply it without knowing anything about the meaning of the various language constructs. All it requires is verifying that a symbol used in some scope also appears in a declaration in an enclosing scope. However, the "also appears" part makes this rule context-sensitive.

That rule is somewhat similar to the constraints mentioned in [this post about Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30698970/1566221) (linked to from one of your comments to your question): that neither a Javascript object definition nor a function parameter list can define the same identifier twice, another rule which is both clearly context-sensitive and clearly syntactic.

In addition, many languages require non-context-free transformations prior to the parse; these transformations are as much part of the grammar of the language as anything else. For example:

- Layout sensitive block syntax, as in Python, Haskell and many data description languages. (Context-sensitive because parsing requires that all whitespace prefixes in a block be the same length.)
- Macros, as in Rust, C-family languages, Scheme and Lisp, and a vast number of others. Also, template expansion, at least in the way that it is done in C++.
- User-definable operators with user-definable precedences, as in Haskell, Swift and Scala. (Scala doesn't really have user-definable precedence, but I think it is still context-sensitive. I might be wrong, though.)

None of this in any way diminishes the value of context-free parsing, neither in practical nor theoretical terms. Most parsers are and will continue to be fundamentally based on some context-free algorithm. Despite a lot of trying, no-one yet has come up with a grammar formalism which is both more powerful than context-free grammars and associated with an algorithm for transforming a grammar into a parser without adding hand-written code. (To be clear: the goal I refer to is a formalism which is more powerful than context-free grammars, so that it can handle constraints like "variables must be declared before they are used" and the other features mentioned above, but without being so powerful that it is Turing complete and therefore undecidable.)

#### Notes

1. Excluding rules which cannot be implemented in a context-free grammar in order to say that the language is context-free strikes me as a most peculiar way to define context-freeness. Of course, if you remove all context-sensitive aspects of a language, you end up with a context-free superset, but it's no longer the same language.

Comment: FWIW, I've seen claims that the C++ grammar is [undecidable](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/defective.html), even if I never found a proof for that. Template metaprogramming, being Turing powerful, does make type checking undecidable, but I don't know if it also interferes with parsing that much to make it undecidable as well.

Comment: @chi: there's an old answer of mine on SO which shows the idea. You define a template class with a single boolean template argument  and specialise the two possibilities. The specialisation on `true` has a public template member class named `x`. In the other one, the member `x` is an integer. Then you instantiate `templ<pred>.x<42>(0)`. Now you need to figure out if `pred` is `true` or `false` in order to know whether `x<42>(0)` is a call to a templated constructor of member type `x`, or the comparison between 0 and the comparison of scalar member x with 42.

Comment: Or you can leave out the 0. Then it's well-formed if pred is true and a syntax error if it's false. In any case, the parse is determined by the compile time evaluation of `pred`; if that's undecidable, so is the parse.

Comment: Great answer. Similar remarks hold about how the word "regular expressions" are used in practical programming languages. They go beyond literal regular expressions but have enough basic similarity to justify the terminology.

Comment: At least in the case of Python, handling indentation is *not* a part of the grammar. It's part of the lexical analysis. Whitespace is converted to indent tokens in the same way that alphanumeric strings are converted into literals and identifiers.

Comment: Also, I think `typedef` is the canonical feature that makes C context-sensitive.

Comment: @chepner It depends. PCRE is essentially non-regular but most non-PCRE engines are indeed regular. RE and ERE as used by most unix commands and the Tcl programming language are regular (at least can be completely compiled into a DFT state machine) and therefore the name Regular Expression and Extended Regular Expression is more than just labels.

Comment: @slebetman: [BREs](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) include back references but not alternation (except for single characters). The first means that they can recognise non-context-free languages (repeated words); the second that they cannot recognise all regular languages. Although EREs don't include back references, most implementations do accept them. Also, I think you meant to notify someone else.

Comment: @SimonRichter: "context-free" is not a synonym for "easy to parse"; not all context-free languages even have deterministic grammars. And neither does "context-sensitive" mean "hard to parse". It just means that the parser requires more state than a stack. (For example, a symbol table.) VHDL might be simultaneously context free and hard to parse (although I think it's another language whose parser requires a symbol table).

Comment: @chepner: `typedef` wouldn't be problematic if it weren't for the ambiguity in the syntax for a cast. There is also a corner case in the syntax for declarations, more evident in C++, but that syntax could be adjusted to avoid the issue. (In some other language, i mean. In C, we're stuck with it.)

Comment: Non-left recursive PEGs are linear time parseable with [packrat parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410477/what-is-packrat-parsing). In any case, a general CFG is cubic time ([Earley parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earley_parser)), still quadratic for unambiguous grammars. Once you're down to LL(k) or LR(k), comparing to non-left recursive PEG is appropriate.

Comment: @obscurans: Actually, I'd misremembered the power of PEGs; they can parse (some) grammars which would require unbounded lookahead for an LL or LR parser, but they cannot parse languages which don't have a context-free grammar (as far as I know). In my mind, I had them confused with a comment by Terrence Parr about being able to parse (certain) context-sensitive languages with ANTLR4; it's true that you can do so, but you need to step outside of the grammar formalism to do so. (Actual executable code is required.) So I deleted the note.

Comment: @obscurans: But I don't think that what it used to say is in any way negated by your statement that **non-left recursive** PEGs are linear-time parseable. That's true, but what I said was that **deterministic** CFGs are not necessarily linear-time parseable. Some deterministic CFGs are left-recursive, so the two claims are capable of peacefull coexistence :-). (And there's a difference between deterministic and non-ambiguous CFGs. A deterministic CFG cannot be ambiguous, but non-ambiguous CFGs can certainly be non-deterministic. Classical example: even-length palindromes.)

Comment: I don't know about the other languages, but in Swift you can parse user definable operators using a context free grammar, giving you a sequence of expressions separated by operators, without knowing names, associativity and precedence of actually defined operators. You can examine such a sequence later when the operators are known. (And tell the user there is no operator named +-+-+, or there is a conflict due to associativity, or you can determine the order the operators need to be evaluated).

Comment: @gnasher729: pretty well any language can be parsed by first transforming the input using a context free transducer and then passing the result through an ad hoc computation performed by Turing complete mechanism. That makes the cfg useful. But it doesn't make the language context-free. A language is context free iff you can determine whether or not a sentence is part of the language using a PDA. This question is tagged [tag:formal-languages] and in that context, Swift is not a context-free language. That's not a criticism of Swift nor does it say cfg parsing is pointless. It's just a fact.

Comment: Speaking of Swift and undecidability, [Swift type-checking is undecidable](https://forums.swift.org/t/swift-type-checking-is-undecidable/39024).

Comment: @rici, the problem in Swift is that lots of information is made available only long after it is required, so the compiler needs to be able to parse input without having the info available. (It's amazing when you've grown up with Pascal). The problem is easiest solved by having a language "Swift structural" which can be parsed with a CFG, and a language "Swift actual" which is a subset and which applies all kinds of rules.

Comment: @gnasher729: being context free isn't a virtue. As I said, it's just a mathematical fact. I'm not saying that swift is unparseable or even particularly hard to parse. I just used it as an example of a language which has a useful feature which cannot be expressed with a CFG. That's true, unremarkable, and in no way a criticism. Almost all languages have context-sensitive aspects, and a CS student should be aware of what they are so that they can recognise them. Those languages also (mostly) have context-free aspects, and a parser will have both components.

Comment: @rici "no-one yet has come up with a grammar formalism which is both more powerful than CFGs and associated with an algorithm for transforming a grammar into a parser without adding hand-written code.". Per my limited understanding of such things, **Raku rules**, which I think are an analytical grammar formalism, manage this, provided one manually excludes left recursive rules. Presuming this is so, is it notable? Presuming it's not,, could you comment on, or provide a link explaining, why not? And if you don't know, how would a non-academic go about establishing if it is or not?

Comment: @raiph: that's a good question, but unfortunately a comment thread on SO is probably not a good place to ask it. There's lots I could say about Raku, very little relevant to the original question here, so let me limit myself to this: what Raku calls grammars are programs written in a Turing complete programming language. That's undoubtedly convenient as a domain specific language, but most useful analyses of Turing-complete computation are necessarily undecidable. So there was already a Turing complete formalisms available: Turing machines. And, for that matter, context-sensitive grammars...

Comment: @ralph: when Chomsky devised his hierarchy of grammars in the early 60s,  he was searching for a formalism powerful enough to describe human language, which is context sensitive, but not so powerful that automated analysis was impossible. He was not successful in that quest,; in that sense, the Chomsky hierarchy is an extremely useful failure. One of the wonderful things about computation theory is that sometimes a complete failure is a vital forward step. Another vastly useful failure was the 1968 Algol report...

Comment: @ralph: We still haven't found it, so it's still a great place for original research. Raku is a fascinating experiment, but it's a deliberately unconstrained formalism (if it really can be described as a formalism). But it's not a formalism for which you can envisage an automated correctness proof, for example. It may turn out to be the tool of choice for writing ad hoc parsers. Or not.

Comment: Great answer, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The boundary between context-free and context-sensitive is only determined by *one thing*: whether or not it can be decided with a nondeterministic pushdown automata.

With respect to grammar specifically, most practical programming languages are *almost* context-free if not context-free, but the context-free/context-sensitive distinction isn't nearly as important as the ease of parsing. It's possible to create a context-free language that is difficult to parse or is ambiguous, and it is also possible to create a context-sensitive language that is easy to parse. Remember, the computers we use to parse programming languages are functionally equivalent to Turing machines (if given infinite memory) and are limited by the fact that they are deterministic. The determinism is the practical limiting factor that informs our choice in grammars that programming languages will use, so the boundary between context-free and context-sensitive is less practically interesting than the boundary between deterministic and nondeterministic.

$LL_k$ and $LALR_k$ grammars form specific subsets of deterministic context-free grammars that can be parsed with generated tables within programs that simulate a deterministic pushdown automaton (which is less powerful than a nondeterministic one).

On the other hand, $PEG$ grammars have a handful of features that technically fall under the context-sensitive umbrella, however they can be parsed in linear time<sup>*</sup> with generated code, which outperforms generalized nondeterministic context-free parsing (The best known algorithm for CFGs is somewhere between quadratic and cubic time. This class of grammars includes certain obscure features that are technically context-free but are hard to parse- I don't know of any examples off the top of my head). PEGs have become quite popular for modern languages, and even Python has adopted its use for upcoming versions and new languages such as Zig have been using them from the beginning.

Having a "more powerful" grammar doesn't matter at all for the power of a programming language because the computing model they represent can simulate a Turing machine. In fact, it's often the opposite because "more powerful" grammars tend to be more difficult to parse and are therefore less friendly to both machines and computers (and slower to compile). C++ is a particularly notorious offender in this realm, with templates (and how they are expanded) having the ability to affect the parse tree. In fact, C++ is not even decidable because templates are Turing complete.

<sub>*: Technically, there are some pathological cases that can cause catastrophic backtracking and explode the parsing to exponential time, however for most useful grammars and programs, this is not an issue. In addition, since PEG parsers typically cache intermediate parsing results, two rules that only differ slightly will not cause a tremendous amount of backtracking in order to properly select the correct rule, and smart code generators can mitigate the worst backtracks.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

For a detailed discussion how C as standardized in 2011 (see ISO/IEC 9899:2011 – Programming languages – C) diverges from context freeness you might want to look at Jourdan and Poitier, ["A simple, possibly correct LR parser for C11"](http://gallium.inria.fr/%7Efpottier/publis/jourdan-fpottier-2016.pdf), ACM Transactions on Programming Languages and Systems 39:4 (Aug 2017), article 14. And that one assumes preprocessed code (already mangled by the C preprocessor).

Note that the preprocessor has *no* idea or respect for C syntax, and can be (perversely) used to rename keywords and partially replace syntax. An (in)famous example is the dialect of C deformed into almost-Algol in which Bourne wrote his original version of the Unix shell (see the [V7 shell source](https://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/src/cmd/sh)).

The history of Algol 68 with its two-level grammar (the idea was to have a grammar generating a grammar tailored to the program) is also a data point showing programming languages are not context free.

Even a language with extremely simple "context free" syntax like Scheme as described by the [R7RS](https://small.r7rs.org) (its syntax isn't much more than "open parenthesis has to be closed") is accompanied by a lot of non-context-free restrictions in its description.

Answer (score 1):

On top of what others have said, many modern programming languages come with explicit disambiguation rules, and non-compiler-writers are often not aware of just how often these are applied.

Most modern programming languages have a two-level grammar, split into lexical analysis and syntax analysis. The lexical language in particular is almost always based on two disambiguation rules:

- Some lexemes take precedence over others. For example, an identifier is a sequence of characters of a certain form which isn't a keyword. This *can* be expressed as a grammar or regular expression (regular languages are closed under set difference), but it's difficult
- Lexemes are as long as possible. This is known as the "maximal munch rule". So, for example, `ifwhile` is a single identifier rather than the two keywords `if` and `while`.

Similarly, it is *possible* to solve the "dangling else" problem with an unambiguous grammar, but it's more typically solved using a CFG form of the maximal munch rule ("prefer shift to reduce" in LR speak).

Having said that, there are languages whose grammars are inherently ambiguous, and disambiguation must happen semantically. The C family of languages famously has several places where this occurs:

- In C, `foo(bar);` is a function call if `foo` is an identifier, or a declaration of a variable named `bar` if `foo` is a type name. In C++, it could also be a function-style cast of `bar` to type `foo`.
- In C++, `foo bar();` could be a declaration of a function named `bar`, or it could be a declaration of a variable named `bar` using the default constructor of `foo`.